# Grouping Values In A Certain Range For a Plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, binning

So I have a dataframe that looks like this.

```
name value
<int> <fct>
1    1
2    2.5
3    8
4    6
5    8
6    25
7    28
8    3
9    12
10   1.5
11   0.5
12   8
13   0.8
14   1.8
15   12
16   0.00594
17   1.2
18   3
19   1.25
20   5
21   300
22   38
```

I want to plot a graph where on the x-axis whole numbers are shown (0,5,10,15,...,40) and then a special group called 40+. On the y-axis it is how many values from my dataframe above are between those numbers. For example, between 35 and 40 should only be 1 value.

Initially, I thought a histogram would be suitable. However, my variables seemed to be discrete and histograms deals more with density and probability.

How can I go about this? I'd like to use ggplot2 if possible.

Comment: Could you show us the code you have tried so far and paste your data into the  question using `dput(your_data)`. Try to mutate your value into numeric `as.numeric(df$value)` then you could plot a histogram.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're interested in a bar plot - similar to a histogram, but with user-defined categories instead of auto-generated divisions.

We use `cut` and `table` functions to calculate the total number in each category, then calculate 40+ separately.

```r
library(ggplot2)
v <- data.frame(name=1:20, value=rnorm(20, mean = 20, sd=20))

cats <- table(cut(v$value, breaks = seq(0, 40, 5)))
fortyplus <- sum(v$value>40)

dat <- data.frame(range=c(names(cats), "40+"),
           count=c(as.numeric(cats), fortyplus))
ggplot(dat) + geom_bar(aes(x=range, y=count), stat = "identity")
```

Comment: Error in cut.default(Bounty_Worth_DF$value, breaks = seq(0, 40, 5)) : 
  'x' must be numeric ----> this is the error message I get

Comment: Try `Bounty_Worth_DF$value <- as.numeric(as.character(Bounty_Worth_DF$value))` before this code. It looks like it's currently encoded as a factor rather than a numeric vector

Comment: One problem. (5,10] should be right after (0,5] as the 2nd range. However, instead it's right before 40+, the final range. How can I fix this?